# Add dynamic text to dynamically created li

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add a dynamic text to dynamically created li. I have a form with lots of input fields.While submitting the form, I need to check for required and display error messages specific to each field. This is the code I am using currently.

```
<form action="" id="submit_form">
<input class="required" type="text" id="test1" name="test1" title="Field1 required" />
<br/>
<input class="required" type="text" id="test2" name="test2" title="Field2 required" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" />
```

jquery function

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit_form').submit(function () {
        var returnValue = true;
        $('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
            var input = $(this);

            input.next('div.error_text').remove();
            input.removeClass('highlight');

            if (!input.val()) {
                input.addClass('highlight');
                var msg = $(this).attr('title');
                input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'$msg'</li></ul>')
                returnValue = false;
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now if first field is not entered, then I need "Field1 required" error message and for the second field I need "Field2 required". How can I get this title and display in the error li?

Comment: One way would be `><li>'$msg'</li>` -> `><li>'+msg+ '</li>` . Generally it's a better idea to use templates though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to concatenate string

```
input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>')
                                                 ^    ^ // added + here
```